# iOS Notification For Music Start Playing

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine

I'm working on a game made in Unity and I'm trying to handle the case where the player has headphones that have a remote control built into them. The player presses the play button on the remote control while playing the game and music from a backgrounded music app begins playing. Ideally, we would capture this event and turn our music off but I can't seem to find a notification that is triggered in this situation. I've tried the following in AppController.mm:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication*)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary*)launchOptions
{
    ...

    // music notifications
    NSNotificationCenter *notificationCenter = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];

    [notificationCenter
     addObserver: self
     selector:    @selector (handlePlaybackStateChanged:)
     name:        MPMusicPlayerControllerNowPlayingItemDidChangeNotification
     object:      [MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer]];

    [[MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer] beginGeneratingPlaybackNotifications];

    return NO;
}

- (void)handlePlaybackStateChanged:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    NSLog(@"Playback State: %d", [MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer].playbackState);
    //if([[MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer].playbackState
}
```

Does anyone know of a notification that is actually triggered in this case or a way that I can identify this situation? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried inverting the order of the commands? You probably need to first start generating the notifications, and only after that add yourself as an observer. The notifications that get posted are 
MPMusicPlayerControllerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification, 
MPMusicPlayerControllerNowPlayingItemDidChangeNotification, and
MPMusicPlayerControllerVolumeDidChangeNotification.

Answer (score 1):

Modifications in `AppControler.mm` will be lost on Unity updates. The safer way is to place all native code in folder *Assets/Plugins/iOS*, s. [Building Plugins for iOS](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/PluginsForIOS.html) for more information.

I made a small plugin called [iPodHandlerPlugin on gitHub](https://github.com/kayy/iPodHandlerPlugin). Just put the lib file in *Assets/Plugins/iOS* and IPodHandler somwhere under *Scripts*.

To get notified on state changes follow the instructions given in the readme.

Maybe a static library is somewhat overdosed. Alternatively you can use the files `iPodHandlerPlugin.mm` and `UnityIPodCallbackListener.m` directly in *Assets/Plugins/iOS*.

Comment: Thanks Kay, I'll give that a shot. I came onto this project and the AppController.mm file was already heavily modified but it is in the Plugins folder so that we can retain the changes that have been made to it. I do not look forward to upgrading from Unity 4.1 though as I've read there are a ton of changes to that file that we will have to merge in.

Comment: Kay, I just took a look at the code and I'm doing the same thing as far as registering for notifications and setting a selector to handle those notifications. However, my notification function isn't being called. Any thoughts on why?

Comment: You are right, your code seems fine so far. To narrow down the problem I would extract the code into a separate class (and file in _Plugins/iOS_) and call it from some `Awake` method?

Comment: Just to confirm, this code should detect if another app is playing music, right? That's what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Yes, and it works like expected in my case. Well in 99.9% while I'm still looking to reproduce the remaining 0.1%. Somthing with facetime calls terminated via headset.